# Objects in JSON looping with $Each, how to get the values

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

i got this function

```
function getAllDays(year,month){


var getdate = new Date();  //Used to prevent caching during ajax call
$.getJSON("AantalUrenAjax?_d" +(new Date().getTime()) +"&jaar=" + year + "&maand=" +       month ,function(data)
{
     $.each(data, function(index, value) 
   {

windows.alert(('#Dag').val(value.Maand));
    }); 
    });
```

the JSON the ajax call gives me is:

```
 [{"Dag":"2013","Maand":"10","Jaar":"01","aantalafspraken":0},        
  {"Dag":"2013","Maand":"10","Jaar":"02","aantalafspraken":0},       
  {"Dag":"2013","Maand":"10","Jaar":"03","aantalafspraken":0},
 ]
```

How can i retrieve the values?

```
windows.alert(('#Dag').val(value.Maand));
```

Crashes :(

Comment: Are your labels correct? Why do you have the year labeled as Day, and vice versa?

Comment: also you have an extra `v` at the beginning of the function that can create a js error

Comment: the v was a typo here, and yes the labels are switched, my fault, but that shouldn't give an error

Comment: `('#Dag')` is a string.  It doesn't have a `.val()` method.  I think you forgot a `$`.  `$('#Dag').val()`.  Also, alerting that, won't give you anything useful.  Try `console.log` instead.

Comment: Debugging with alert sucks! Use the console instead. Every error will be printed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few syntax errors in your code. There's a stray `v` at the top of your function, `windows.alert` should be `window.alert`. You're missing the `$` in front of your jQuery call. You're also alerting the jQuery object that you're setting the value to, not the value itself. You probably want:

```
window.alert(value.Maand);
$('#Dag').val(value.Maand);
```

Comment: It's actually a pretty common syntax error. I've seen it a few times. If you think your code might have syntax errors, try running your code through a linter like jslint.com. It will not just tell you errors in your code, but also offer ways to make your code better in general.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be more like this maybe?

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  console.log(value.Maand);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
   dagValue = value.Dag; // dagValue will be "2013"
   maandValue = value.Maand; //maandValue will be "10"
   ...
```